# my bitnami wamp vhost doesn't working properly

Tags: php, apache, laravel, wamp, bitnami

**I use:**

- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- Bitnami WAMP Stack 5.6.22-0
- Laravel 5

**What I have done:**

1. Edit my `%systemroot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file by adding `127.0.0.1  juke.dev` in the end of the line
2. Edit my `httpd.conf` by

   - uncomment the line `LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so`
   - uncomment the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
3. Edit my `httpd-vhosts.conf` into this:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAdmin root@localhost
       DocumentRoot "C:/WAMP/apache2/htdocs/claim/public"
       ServerName juke.dev
           <Directory "C:/WAMP/apache2/htdocs/claim/public">
           Require all granted
           </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Install `composer` and `laravel5`
5. Edit my `laravel5` `routes.php` into this:

   ```
   Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
   Route::get('contact', 'WelcomeController@contact');
   ```
6. And the `WelcomeController` is like this:

[image: SS controller]

**Now into the problem**

- When I go to `juke.dev`, it success.

[image: juke.dev ss]

- When I go to `juke.dev/contact`, it fails.

[image: juke.dev/contact SS]

- When I go to `localhost/claim/public/contact`, it success.

[image]

What did I do wrong?

I'm still new in web programming, so any explanation would be help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strange problem:

This is an example of my vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "G:\Google Drive\Data\Proj\public"
    ServerName rethinkdb.i
    ServerAlias www.rethinkdb.i
    <Directory "G:\Google Drive\Data\Proj\public">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The other thing I can think is maybe your .htaccess file.
How does that look?

Edited:
Just tried with your vhost, and have the same problem. So try to use the virtualhost here above.